# Image service for a Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I am creating and application that need to save images. I don't want to write it if it already exits, Anyone know of a product that I can use so I don't have to develop mine. I am using asp.net MVC. What I want is something with and API that I can save to and retrieve to ( I don't want to store the images in my system if its possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using the [FLICKR.NET API](http://www.codeplex.com/FlickrNet) for my website (which is ASP.NET - MVC) and love it!

Answer (score 3):

[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) also has a [.NET API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/developers_guide_dotnet.html) (which I use with success)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image file already (i.e. someone uploads it) and just want a place to put it that's not your local machine or your database you can look into using some sort of cloud-storage system like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (Note: this will cost you money).  You can then use a library like [ThreeSharp](http://threesharp.codeplex.com/).  You can also have Amazon serve up the images instead of your webserver.

If you don't already have the images, i.e. you want to generate images, you'll need to be more specific on what exactly you need.  There is a wide array of libraries and some are better suited for certain scenarios than others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flickr to store your images.  Alternately you could also use a service like ImageShack.

Answer (score 0):

[Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) has an [api](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) that will allow you to manage images.